# Find the classes of given languages?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Consider the following statements

1. $L_1 = \{wxw^R \mid w∈(a,b)^*, x∈c\}$
2. $L_2 = \{wy \mid w,y∈(a,b)^*\}$
3. $L_3 = \{zwz \mid w∈(a,b)^*,z∈\{a\}\}$
4. $L_4 = \{wxw \mid w∈(a,b)^*,x∈\{c\}^*\}$

Find the classes of languages?

---

My attempt:

Obviously $L_1$ is deterministic context free language.

$L_2$ is regular language as regular expression is $(a,b)^*(a,b)^*$.

$L_3$ is also regular language as regular expression is $a(a,b)^*a$.

> I'm stuck at $L_4$ it seems context sensitive language but not context free language

Can you explain in formal way, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language $L_4$ is not context-free. Indeed, if it was, then $L_4 \cap \{a,b\}^* = \{ ww \mid w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$ would also be context-free. But it is not: see for instance this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) by Brian M. Scott.